# Redirecting stdout and stderr output to a file using system command doesn't work in perl

Tags: perl, bash, perl-module

When I try to redirect stdout and stderr output of a command onto a file. There is nothing which gets written into a file. This is in a Perl script. I want the stdout and stderr output of a command to be redirected to a file. The code I wrote is this:

```
system("sudo rm a.txt &>> output.txt");
```

The file `output.txt` doesn't contain anything at all. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
system("sudo rm a.txt >> output.txt 2>&1")
```